# Tezos Origination operation - How to do it correctly from programming?

Tags: origination

I am implementing the "delegation" and "origination" methods in TezosJ_SDK_plainJava.

Occurs that, the origination method I wrote, although is creating an operation and writing it to the blockchain correctly, it appears as "pink" (failure).

Here is the operation I am sending to the blockchain:

[{"delegate":"tz1S37hEZnNrAXfzuRYSjG9Qxq8VrwpWaukB"
,"spendable":true
,"gas_limit":"10000"
,"storage_limit":"257"
,"balance":"2000000"
,"manager_pubkey":"tz1S37hEZnNrAXfzuRYSjG9Qxq8VrwpWaukB"
,"kind":"origination"
,"fee":"1730"
,"delegatable":true
,"source":"tz1S37hEZnNrAXfzuRYSjG9Qxq8VrwpWaukB"
,"counter":"1086164"}]

It does not give me errors, but when I check on the chain, I got a pink line:
https://tzscan.io/opH2gaV3tD8CgzQ74aEhwq3iLbQzNxfMExzjSW4qjPxQjDtwsA1?default=origination

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delegate address must be registered as a baker on the blockchain. It should give you an error message if you do the pre-apply before injecting the operation.

Comment: That was it. I was passing the wrong address for the delegate.